# Struts Ajax request taking long time

Tags: struts2

I am using Struts ajax call for displaying data in JSP

```
<sx:a id="testReport" formId="testform" targets="testdiv">
```

This request is taking long time.Could you someone help me if there is a way to show loading image or blur the screen until Struts AJAX request is completed.

Comment: What is a taglib prefix for in this tag?

Comment: @Roman C strust-dojo

Comment: OT: Dojo plugin is deprecated, switch to struts 2 jquery plugin (struts.jgeppert.com/) if you can !

Comment: It is very old application. For new changes, I will use struts 2 jquery plugin. Thank you so much for your suggestion. @AlirezaFattahi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not shown your ajax call
Assuming ajax call should be like this you can try:
**Show Image before making the ajax request, and hide it after Ajax call completes**

```
$('#loading-image').show();
$.ajax({
    url: uri,
    success: function(html){
        // Code here after success
    },
    complete: function(){
        $('#loading-image').hide();
    }
});
```

You can also show **Modal Div** behind your image so user can not interact with page while Ajax call is going on:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

</div>
```

`css` for your **modal div**

```
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}
```

**BTW:** this is done by using **jQuery and css** not a **struts** issue

**UPDATE**:

OK You are using `struts-dojo plugin`
Have look at this then
You are looking for **`indicator`** attribute, I think so:

```
<img id="loadingImage" src="images/loadingAnimation.gif" style="display:none"/>
<sx:a id="testReport" formId="testform" targets="testdiv" showLoadingText="false" indicator="loadingImage">
```

This link will help you [AjaxandJavaScriptRecipes-Showindicatorwhilerequestisinprogress](https://struts.apache.org/docs/ajax-and-javascript-recipes.html#AjaxandJavaScriptRecipes-Showindicatorwhilerequestisinprogress)

Comment: I tried this one but didn't work. Below is the code for Ajax call..<sx:a id="testReport" formId="testform" targets="testdiv">